# Go through a object attributes that contains numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a object with these properties and i have a list of booleans(the type of properties).
I want to go through my object attributes and associate the values of my list.
Example:

My list(0) is D1.
My list(1) is N1
My list(2) is D2
My list(3) is N2
The problem is that i dont have just 7, i have 60 of these.
What is the best way to do it?

Thank you

```
public bool D1 { get; set; }
public bool N1 { get; set; }

public bool D2 { get; set; }
public bool N2 { get; set; }

public bool D3 { get; set; }
public bool N3 { get; set; }

public bool D4 { get; set; }
public bool N4 { get; set; }

public bool D5 { get; set; }
public bool N5 { get; set; }

public bool D6 { get; set; }
public bool N6 { get; set; }

public bool D7 { get; set; }
public bool N7 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image.

Comment: Can you change the way the object is defined? In general if you have a bunch of properties with sequential numerals in their names, you are probably doing it wrong. It is almost always preferable to use something that takes an index as argument, such as a list, array, or indexed property.

Comment: Do it once in the constructor

Comment: Where did that object come from? Did someone actually write 60 properties by hand? If this comes from deserializing a JSON or XML string, you could change the deserialization code and retrieve those values as arrays or lists. In JSON for example, you could deserialize to a Dictionary instead of an object and get all pairs as entries in the dictionary

Comment: Is is to save to each user a boolean for each day of the month (day and night)
I build the object by hand and it is to save in database and then show in a calendar.